# I have a problem in @query ( in repository ) in spring boot

Tags: java, mysql, spring, swagger

I would like to display all the publications witch the user have subscribed in it . I have 3 tables publications , user , subscription( the table subscription contains enum is called  etat(subscribe or subscribed )

this is my code in the repository publication

```
@Repository
public interface PublicationRepository extends CrudRepository<Publication, Integer> {
    
    @Query(value="select  * from publication JOIN user u JOIN subscription s where s.etat=:etat", nativeQuery = true)
        List<Publication> pubs(@Param("etat") Etat etat);
    }
```

and this is the code in my controller

```
@RestController
@Api(tags = "Publication management")
@RequestMapping("/publication")
public class PublicationRestController {
    
    @Autowired
    PublicationServiceImpl publicationService;
    @Autowired
    PublicationRepository pr;
    
    @GetMapping("/pubs/{etat}")
    public List<Publication> pubs(@PathVariable("etat") Etat etat) {
      return pr.pubs(etat);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Details of the compiler or runtime error?  (It looks like the query is invalid.)

Comment: no  error in compiler .. it's  display error 500 in swagger when i test

Comment: a JOIN needs an ON clause, else mysql will thriow an error

Comment: A 500 error means that there will very likely be a stack trace in your log file on the server. You need to learn to find the log file and look at it.

Comment: Could you copy the Publication class?

Comment: @JaumeMoróniTarrasa YES